# Php code for getting the first frame of a video(flv)

Tags: php

I have using flow player for playing my .flv videos.How i can create a thumbnail from the first frame.Is their any inbuilt Php code for doing this one.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know of is using FFMPEG. I have never used this script, but looking at it seems to be what you need, and may need some tweaking.

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/447/show-first-frame-as-preview-image

**EDIT**

To get the image / display it you would just use the html code:

```
<img src="http://my.domain.com/path-to-file/ffmpeg_image.php?file=video.flv&time=00:00:00&browser=false" />
```

From what I gathered from that script. But of course, it would probably be better to, when you upload the video, run that and generate a "cache" of the image so that whole process does not have to run for each call.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for but a good way of showing the first frame of a video in flowplayer is to set autobuffering to true:

```
    clip: {
        autoPlay: false,
        autoBuffering: true,
    }
```

This will load the video (wich might be very bad for you).

To do it yourself you need something like ffmpeg installed on your system. if it is installed check [this out](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=137110).

Comment: Is any other method for doing this one

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, some guy on the forums needed something similar and I tried to help him, idiot-proof style. Check out the last post on this thread. I hope it helps.

[link](http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?p=10960577#post10960577)