# How to get a snapshot of the first frame of a .flv in PHP?

Tags: php, flv

And save it as an image.

Is this kind of job possible in PHP?

Answer (score 5):

PHP has an [`ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/) library which you can use for this. Utilizing `ffmpeg_movie` you can return a video file as an object:

`$movie = new ffmpeg_movie('/path/to/.flv');`

You can then go on and use the `getFrame()` method, which returns the frame as an `ffmpeg_frame` object, which has the method `toGDImage()` which returns a `GD` image of the frame. Obviously the `GD` library needs to be enabled.

Comment: @lex You can have a look at: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3747-PHP-Manipulate-and-convert-videos-with-ffmpeg-program.html Although I have not used it or read through it.

Answer (score 1):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494007/php-code-for-getting-the-first-frame-of-a-videoflv).

All the solutions seem to rely on FFMPEG (so it's unlikely this would work on shared web hosting, for example).